# Connection OCI8 for PHP on IIS7 windows 2008

Tags: php, oci8

I have PHP application running on IIS7, windows 2008 R2 server

i try to connect to remote Oracle DB, i installed PHP on the IIS7 useing web platform installer, then enabled the following extension :
php_oci8.dll, php_oci8_11g.dll, php_pdo_oci.dll

when i run phpinfo i can't find oci8 enabled in the extensions.

this is my function to connect

```
<?php

function oci_query_assoc($oconn,$query){
$result = oci_parse($query);
oci_execute($oconn,$result);
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($result)){
$return[] = $row;
}
return $return;
}

function oci_query_assoc_single($oconn,$query){
$result = oci_parse($query);
oci_execute($oconn,$result);
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($result)){
$return = $row;
}
return $return;
}

?>
```

Comment: If it is not in your PHPinfo then the module is not installed correctly and you wont be able to use it in your code. Check your logs for more info

Answer (score 0):

Now check in php_info(); that oci8 enables or not if enable then use standard oci8 connections

This is your standard Oracle connection

```
include('database.php'); //which have database credentials and server name stored

  $c = oci_connect($userName, $password, "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =$serverName)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$databaseName)))");

print_r($c);
```

and let me know wether it is work or not

and congrats... you combined 3 separate services Oracle, Microsoft, PHP.