# configure php to connect in oracle g11 OCI8

Tags: php, oracle, iis-7, oci8

I am trying to configure php (7.0) to connect to Oracle 11g in a IIS7 server

I uncommented the extension and php_oci8.dll php_oci8_11g but i have this problem

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' -
>   n'est pas une application Win32 valide. (is not a valid Win32 application.)

someone can help me.
thanks.

Comment: Have you read and followed the [Installing/Configuring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) section of the manual?

Comment: yes but I m not understand this error when it comes

Comment: PHP 7.x only includes `php_oci8_12c.dll` so I assume you've downloaded `php_oci8.dll` and `php_oci8_11g.dll` from somewhere.  Try using *only* the included DLL (it's backwards compatible all the way back to Oracle 9).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this answer.
you need to install oci8 driver in extension as well as system32 in window server

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34494636/2125924
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/24796250/2125924

check these both answers